# Generating a schedule from a google doc of members' availability

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google doc spreadsheet that contains information on every member of a group's availability to meet at certain times of the week. There are multiple meetings that need to take place during the week, with different members of the group needing to be at certain meetings. I need a way to generate a schedule based on this such that the most members can attend each meeting. None of the meetings can take place during the same time slot.

The table contains a row for each meeting that takes place. Each column represents a time slot (eg. Mon 6:30pm-8:00pm) that the meetings can take place. The cells corresponding to a certain meeting and a certain time slot contain a number representing the number of people that can attend each meeting. If the cell contains the same number as the number of members signed up for the meeting, then the cell gets highlighted automatically by google docs.

I am trying to solve this problem through the use of google docs' scripting capabilities to do this, but I am having trouble figuring out the algorithm. All I really need is some pseudocode and I can write it.

Assume in my script I have a two-dimensional array of the cells, as well as a two-dimensional boolean array corresponding to whether the cell is highlighted (meaning the maximum members can be in attendance)

Here is an example of what the table looks like:

```
|Meeting    |Mon 6:30-8:30pm |Mon 8:30-10:30pm |Tue 6:30-8:30pm |Tue 8:30-10:30pm |
|-----------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------------|
|Meeting 1  |7               |9                |8               |6                |
|Meeting 2  |3               |5                |1               |4                |
|Meeting 3  |10              |15               |12              |8                |
|-----------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------------|
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're saying, you're going to have to start by choosing the order to schedule the meetings. The best way I can think of, given that it sounds like all else is equal, is to begin by simply choose the meeting which the most people can attend:

```
firstScheduled = max(max(meeting1), max(meeting2), max(meeting3));
```

After that, look at the remaining meetings and see which one has the highest possible attendance on the currently unscheduled days:

```
foreach meeting as m
    foreach day as d
        if d is currently scheduled
            m = 0  // set all attendees to 0; no one can come, since the'll be
                   // at the other meeting
        end if
    end for

    highestAttendanceDate = max(meeting1)
end for
```

Then just iterate that through until all meetings are scheduled.

Comment: That worked really well. Here's the final code in javascript https://gist.github.com/923491 Thanks for the help!